# Upgrade Bluetooth in Toyota 2009 Camry Hybrid

Tags: toyota, bluetooth

I have a Toyota Camry 2009 Hybrid with a Nav system and the bluetooth is pretty old. It can't stream, and it gets all confused when multiple phones are paired to it. (It only connects to the last paired phone automatically.) I'd like to upgrade the sound system to *anything* that supports modern BlueTooth.

What are my options? It seems that there is no software update available. But I've had a hard time finding after-market stereo systems that will allow me to unplug the Nav System / DVD / Radio / Etc and have the new one "just work."  (They claim to do this, but I'm not sure.)

Then the other question --- how hard is this to do?  And what does it do to my extended warrantee?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a [product recommendation question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad/185486#185486).

Comment: I'd have a conversation with crutchfield. They're probably going to have the most up to date information about what might fit. Usually if you can find a replacement that is a direct fit, they are quite pricey. You could abandon any kind of upgrade and get a standalone unit. (Example: http://www.parrot.com/usa/products/bluetooth-hands-free-car-kits/) These kits work pretty well and they are generally updated on a regular basis.

Comment: Can I use a radio from a more recent Camry Hybrid?